# How to make a generated pdf non editable in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a banking client for whom I have designed an iOS app where we will populate all the client details onto the account opening application pdf forms and generate the final pdf with all the client details. I am generating a pdf using CoreGraphics. But the pdf is editable in Adobe Acrobat Pro and they are able to edit the contents of the application form. Is there any method to restrict the editing of the pdf after it is generated from CoreGraphics? I have encrypted the pdf with a password But the client needs the pdf to be non editable.

Comment: I don't believe there are any features like that in the simple CoreGraphics implementation of PDF. Typically when I need advanced PDF features, I turn to https://pspdfkit.com.

Comment: You probably want to open the pdf for view only within your app.

Answer (score 0):

See [Protecting PDF Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-BCIBGJFC)

Reading between the lines a bit — because the docs are not overly clear — I think that when you create the PDF context using `CGPDFContextCreate()`, you pass a dictionary into its auxiliaryInfo, using the key `kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword` and a value that's some arbitrary password string. This encrypts the document so that only the owner (there people with that password) can work with the contents. It doesn't say it prevents editing explicitly, but I'm guessing that's implied because it list out special keys to block printing and copying (preventing editing seems like the thing one would *always* want when encrypting a pdf).